# how to get data from mysql in php based on url?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a page table in mysql db with 'page_name', 'title', content, 'author' fields. I want to get it with php like http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=page_name . How do i do it ? pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the GET parameter using the super global $_GET array:

```
$pagename = $_GET['page'];
```

Then write a query for the database. Note that you have to escape every data that comes from the outside:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM page_table WHERE page_name = '%s' LIMIT 1";
$sql = sprintf(%sql, mysql_real_escape_string($pagename));
```

Then execute the query and check that it worked.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) {
    // error occured
}
```

Use the function `mysql_fetch_assoc` to access the data:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You can now access all data in this asscociative array:

```
echo $data["title"];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the database server and select a datbase (e.g. using [mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and [mysql_select_db](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php))
2. Create a SQL query using values from the `$_GET` array
3. Send the query to the database (e.g using [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php))
4. Retrieve the result (e.g. using [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php))
5. Display the data from the result (e.g. using [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php))

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
   // get page
   $page_name = $_GET["page"];

   // Do the query
   $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages_table` WHERE `page_name` LIKE '$page_name'");
   // loop the get the results
   while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($q){
       $db_title = $result["title"];
       $db_content = $result["content"];
       $db_author = $result["author"];
   }

   //put the data together and echo
   echo "
      <h1>$db_title</h1>
      <p>$db_content</p>
      <h3>Author: $db_author</h3>
   ";

?>
```

Dont forget to connect to the db first! And do some checks on the `$_GET[]` for sql injections!!

**EDIT**
Depends on your php installation. If you don't have magic quotes enabled you could do something like `$page_nameClean = addslashes($page_name);` when you do a query or if you know that you are only going to use numbers to get the page (ex: `domain.com?page=1232`) you could do a check:

```
if(is_numeric($page_name)){
   // get the page out of the DB
}else{
   // Show an error message
}
```

Or have a look at this: [avoid code injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875/best-way-to-avoid-code-injection-in-php)

Comment: how do i perform checks on $_GET[]  ? could you pls give me example code ?