# How to execute an included script without being called?

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP script that and at a certain point i want to include another script, but i want the script to run as if it is apart of the original file and doesn't have to be called by a function or a class:

```
if(strpos('X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook', $raw_headers)) {
include 'outlookImageParse.php';
outlookImageParse($html_part);
```

but the included script doesn't work even when i define it as a function in that file and call it from the original. I've used, require, require_once, include_once, but none perform as how i want it to. What to do to get what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `i want the script to run as if it is apart of the original file` What?

Comment: Simply including it should work. Be more specific about what you would like to do and what "doesn't work"

Comment: Is your `if` statement getting executed?

Comment: It appears not, if you look at one of my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `include()` (or require, etc) the script is treated as if it were dropped directly into the file, exactly where your `include` was - see the following example.

`file1.php`

```
<?php
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = 123;

include('file2.php');

echo $var4; // echoes "bbq"

$var5 = 123456;
func1($var5); // echoes "Function! 123456"
?>
```

---

`file2.php`

```
<?php
echo $var1; // echoes "hello"

$var4 = 'bbq';
function func1 ($var)
{
    echo 'Function! ' . $var;
}
?>
```

Comment: don't forget about `return` behavior for included files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-130

Comment: Don't forget? I didn't know about it :P Interesting though.

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, though it still isn't treating it as if it we're dropped directly in the file, in fact it doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Sounds like there's something going wrong in your included file - step through it with `echo` and find out if it's going wrong somewhere. If that's not the issue, have a Google for "apache php include not working" :)

Comment: OR, make sure your `if` statement is getting executed.

Comment: Something has to be completely wrong, i searched through my entire script and found nothing blocking/coming in conflict with the following example


`$b23 = "Microsoft Outlook";
if (strpos("Microsoft Outlook", $b23)) {
echo '<h1>Email Client is Microsoft Outlook</h1>';
} else {
echo '<h1>Could not identify Email Client</h1>';
}`

Yet it still prints **Could not identify email client**

Comment: Post the source of `outlookImageParse` and the contents of `$raw_headers` in the first post, then drop another comment on here when it's done :)

Comment: Here is the source of them both:
http://pastebin.com/4i4jMw4M
$html_part is just the source formatting of the e-mail body, as if you were to right click the page and View the source.

Comment: Add `return $html_part;` to the end of your `outlookImageParse` function, then change the call to `$html_part = outlookImageParse($html_part);`

Comment: I did as you said, and still it isn't being included.
You do mean call it as this right?
`if (strpos('X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook', $raw_headers)) {
include ('outlookImageParse.php');
$html_part = outlookImageParse($html_part);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to code injection? You should look at [Best way to avoid code injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875/best-way-to-avoid-code-injection-in-php) for the best practice advise. I don't know if it will make different, I would also put bracket around included file name.