# Trying to dynamically create a query using pdo php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I believe i am almost to the solution but in webdesign almost means next to nothing. If someone wouldn't mind helping me figure out where i am causing an error or need to do more that would be great. Basically i am trying to teach my self sessions and relearn php cause it has been many years. I want to give the user the option to select what field in their profile they would like to change and then submit a new value. when i hit submit i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''lastname' = 'ZIPPI-DO-DAH' WHERE username = 'eric'' at line 1' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/memberProfile.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/memberProfile.php(22): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/memberProfile.php on line 22
```

Here is my (NOW FIXED)code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitUpdate']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $selectField = $_POST['select'];
        $newValue = $_POST['new_value'];
        $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Testing SET $selectField = :newValue WHERE username = :username");
        $sth->execute(array( ':newValue'=> $newValue, ':username'=> $_SESSION['username'] ));
        header("Locatioon: member.php");
        echo 'Field has been updated, thank you.';
    }
```

Here is my form:

```
<form id="updateProfile" method="POST">
                    <div class="inputField">
                        <label for="select">Select what field you want to change below.(firstname is default)</label>
                        <select name="select" id="selectUpdate">
                            <option value="firstname" selected>First name</option>
                            <option value="lastname">Last name</option>
                            <option value="email">Email</option>
                            <option value="message">Message</option>
                            <option value="username">Username</option>
                            <option value="password">Password</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputField">
                        <label for="new_value">New value - place the new value here</label>
                        <input type="text" name="new_value" id="new_value" placeholder="New Value" tabindex="2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputField">
                        <button class="button" name="submitUpdate" id="submitUpdate" tabindex="4">Submit Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, PDO doesn't support that. You can only bind data parameters, not column or table names. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8314043/3794472

Comment: the value of `:selectField` convert to string with single quote which is causing error. you query be like this `UPDATE Testing SET 'lastname' = 'ZIPPI-DO-DAH' WHERE username = 'eric'`

Comment: Surprised no one has said that earlier when i asked at other forums, thank you

Comment: RxV how would i change that. i saw that in the error message but i dont know how to change it

Comment: i think you must use if statement for this.

Comment: so create an if statement with its own unique query depending on what field they selected to change?

Comment: I figured it out. i used the link that Jeremiah had given me. don't need to prepare the table variable i just placed that variable right into the query without binding it.

Comment: yes it is. but i think it must be long code. so goodluck and happy coding.

Comment: take note without binding can cause sql injection.

Comment: you can make your own workaround by whitelisting your input in your columns.

Comment: Not exactly sure what whitelisting is. here is a link i found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875/best-way-to-avoid-code-injection-in-php, but i don't know how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller An example whitelist could be creating an array of allowed columns. Then you would check the input with `in_array()`, use the provided input if found or use a default column / exit if it's not found.

Comment: Wee bit of a typo here `Locatioon` btw ;)

Comment: ohhh ok, i think i understand now. basically making sure the variable the user submitted is an actual table that exist in the database. I will give thaT I TRY, THANK YOU

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller yes thats basically it, just set a pre defined column names so that you'll know.