# URL security hole fixing '../'

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, url-routing

I have facing an issue of URL routing in PHP.

In my localhost I have two project directory:

- 1. project_one:

     - index.php
     - other_directorys
- 2. hacking_script:

     - index.php
     - database_dump.php

when I have to access my project_one I go with `localhost/project_one` this work correct. But when I have input in this `localhost/project_one/../../hacking_script` it's open `localhost/hacking_script/index.php` file.

So how to prevent it, I didn't get any idea. Can I use .htaccess to prevent it? If yes then how?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, when i type `localhost/project_one/../../hacking_script` then it redirect to `localhost/hacking_script/` not came into my `project_one` index.php file

Comment: Show your full `.htaccess` and `index.php` or the routing script.

Comment: i have just plain `index.php` and i don't use `.htaccess` in this project

Comment: That's how the URLs work. Nothing to prevent it. It is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/../questions/36980771/url-security-hole-fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how URLs work in browser. If you have this question's site:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980771
```

And if you try:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/../questions/36980771
```

This will redirect to the same page. This is **Status By Design**.

Comment: not by behaviour but if you hacked some your project `project_one` main directory `www` & you create directory like `hacking_script` and you put some code like `var_dump($_SESSION)` or `var_dump($_COOKIE)` then it also output the whole session or cookie value set in `project_one`

Comment: I finalize that thing, you're right.!!. Ty for your time:)

Comment: Maybe status by design for stackoverflow. But it's not the case, for every software. Imagine `http://example.com/../php/php.ini` will somehow routed to `require('../php/php.ini')`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Depends.

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking about routing, you are speaking about this:

```
Request -> Router -> GetController -> ExecuteAction
```

This means `GetController` will most likly `include` or `require` some files... There is the part, you need to make sure, it is only requiring allowed files. For example with a [whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875/best-way-to-avoid-code-injection-in-php) (Which is the recommended way). Or make sure, that no special characters like `../` are allowed.

Comment: Actually this was my first answer. Then I understood the question in detail and changed my answer. :)